# How to extract certificate and private key PEM strings from PKCS#12 file using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a use case where the user gives a PKCS#12 file and its password as input, and I need both the certificate's and the private key's PEM strings.

I have managed to create a `SecIdentity` using the p12, and its documentation says:

> A SecIdentity object contains a SecKey object and an associated SecCertificate object.

So, I believe I am in the right path, but I couldn't find a way of extracting the `SecKey` and the `SecCertificate` from this `SecIdentity`.

I have also not found a way to get a PEM string from a `SecKey` or `SecCertificate`, but that would only be the last step.

---

This is the code I've used to create the identity:

```
let key: NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
let options: NSDictionary = [key : p12Password]
    
var rawItems: CFArray?
    
let p12Data = try! Data(contentsOf: p12FileUrl)
let data = p12Data! as NSData
let cfdata = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), data.length)!

let result: OSStatus = SecPKCS12Import(cfdata, options, &rawItems)
if result == errSecSuccess {
    let items = rawItems! as! [[String: Any]]
    let firstItem = items[0]
    let identity = firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentity
}
```

-- UPDATE --

I made some more progress, and managed to extract the certificate in a DER format (which I haven't tried to convert to PEM so far - I believe it should be easy), but I still have no idea how to get the private key.

```
if result == errSecSuccess {
    let items = rawItems! as! [[String: Any]]
    let firstItem = items[0]
    let identity = firstItem[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentity

    var cert: SecCertificate?
    SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &cert)
    var certDer = SecCertificateCopyData(cert!) //DER format
        
    var key: SecKey?
    SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identity, &key)
    let keyDict = SecKeyCopyAttributes(key!) //Not sure what we can find here
}
```

Comment: Hi, Are you able to find a solution.

Comment: @UdayM I've ended up using a cpp implementation for that, didn't find a way to do it in Swift

Comment: Appreciate it if you can share the implementation details.